# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported: POST

Tags: php, laravel

My form:

```
 @if(!empty($Product) && !empty($ProductSpec))
            <form action="{{route('update_product')}}" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="product_code">Product Code</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="product_code" id="product_code" type="text" placeholder="product code..." value="{{$Product->product_code}}">
                    </div>
                    @error('product_code')
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                    @enderror

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update information</button>
                    </div>
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                </form>
                @endif
```

Routes:

```
Route::resource('add_product','ProductController');
Route::get('edit_product', 'ProductController@find_product_index')->name("edit_product");
Route::post('find_product', 'ProductController@find_product')->name("find_product");
Route::post('update_product', 'ProductController@update_product')->name("update_product");

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Controller function:

```
public function update_product(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|max:120|string']);
    return redirect()->route('edit_product')->with('success', 'Product Updated successfully');
}
```

I'm using this code and getting the "Get method is not supported for this route, Supported:POST" error.
Got no idea what is wrong with my code? At first I thought it's my MySQL statements from the controller, but I removed them and I'm still having the same problem.

**EDIT:**
php artisan route:list shows ->
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0M1Zw.png)

Comment: What does `php artisan route:list` say?

Comment: Check documentation.... For update route type PUT/PATCH... and you must edit your form to integrate @method('PUT');

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#restful-partial-resource-routes.    Check just before this title

Comment: run `php artisan route:clear` and try again

Comment: I tried cleaning the routes, but it didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

Your route should be:

```
Route::put('update_product/{update_product} ', 'ProductController@update_product')->name("update_product");
```

Your form should be like:
...............

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
@method('PUT')
</form>
```

Comment: Look at the add_product.update route and see the difference. And you should probably make a route model binding there.

Comment: I switched to add_product.update, but still getting the same error

Comment: I think the problem is that I have 2 forms in 1 page, the first one finds the product by ID and fills information from my database to the second form fields. I think I'm getting this error because there are 2 POST type forms, I guess that's not allowed in php/laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Run `php artisan optimize` to clear and reconfig your cache and routes.
Clearing your routes is not enough.

Comment: I tried that and I get this big error here: https://imgur.com/a/C9zXviS

Comment: Run only then `php artian config:cache` . You error means that in your api routes you have a route that can not be cached. You can also go in there and comment it out, then run the optimize command.

Comment: `php artisan config:cache` worked, but didn't fix the error :(